# Two menus on a navabar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I put two menus in a single navbar?

I want a menu on the left and another on the right, and the menu on the right should not collapse.

Example:

Normal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VoAM.png

Collapsed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQRfH.png

I tried the code below, but when you resize the screen, all the menus are collapsing.

```html
<html>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<!-- Bootstrap JS --> 
<script src="="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GPT</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/index.php">Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/offers.php">Offers
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/withdraw.php">Redeem
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/profile.php">Profile
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/logout.php">Logout
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/index.php">Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/offers.php">Offers
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/withdraw.php">Redeem
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/profile.php">Profile
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    <?= $base_url?>/dashboard/logout.php">Logout
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have the same nav items duplicated? Add the real content you expect for the left and right nav items.

Answer (score 0):

test this :

replace this :

```
<div class="flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
```

with :

```
<div class="flex-row ml-md-auto d-md-flex">
```

Comment: and in the ul add a style flex-direction: row; work fine!